# Где узнать правильное название улицы?

Tags: орфография

В Алматы на табличках улиц есть разные варианты названий улиц: улица Богенбай батыра, улица Карасай Батыра, проспект Абылай хана, улица Толе би

http://2gis.kz/almaty/geo/9430047374967491/center/76.934328%2C43.252177/zoom/17

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80

http://yvision.kz/post/184627

Но по правилам русского языка надо писать: улица Богенбай-батыра, улица Абылай-хана, улица Толе-би?

Как быть?

у Розенталя:

10. В арабских, тюркских, персидских личных именах составные части, обозначающие социальное положение, родственные отношения и т. д., а также служебные слова (ага, ал, аль, ас, аш, бей, бек, бен, заде, зуль, кызы, оглы, оль, паша, уль, хан, шах, эд, эль и др., которые, как правило, присоединяются дефисом) пишутся со строчной буквы: Керим-ага, Зейн ал-Абадеин, Сабах ас-Салем, Омар аш-Шариф, Измаил-бей, Бекир-бек, Ю'суф бен-Хедда, Турсун-заде, Салах-зуль-Фикар, Марзаага кызы Сулейманова, Мамед-оглы (в азербайджанских фамилиях слово оглу пишется отдельно: Алиев Ариф Сарадт оглу, но: Кёроглу), Хаким оль-Мольк, Сулейман-паша, Сейф уль-Ислам, Мирза-хан, Надир-шах, Ахмад эд-Дин, Мохаммед эль-Куни, эс-Зайят, Ахмед ибн аль-Фарид, Абу-ль-Фараджи, Айваз Ошар-оглы, Фахрад-дин-Рази, Джелал-ад-Дин, Мустафа-Зариф-паша, ибн Абд Роббихи, ибн аль-Асир.

Answer (score 3):

Ох, непростой вопрос...
Зависит прежде всего от того, на каком языке эти таблички вообще. 
Если на русском (а надо думать, что именно так), то надо разбираться, кто такое написание установил.
К сожалению, многие государства, особенно те, которые признали русский язык государственным, начали вводить свои правила, перенося те или иные особенности "титульного" языка на язык русский. Этим грешат и "прозападные", и "пророссийские" государства бывшего СНГ. Один Кыргызстан чего стоит. Или та же Бел**а**русь.
Если такая рекомендация выпущена каким-то органом, признанным "управлять" русским языком, то лучше не связываться. Себе дороже. Во всех остальных случаях все-таки надеюсь на возможность если не доказать правоту, то хотя бы безнаказанно *использовать* нормативный для русского вариант.

Конкретно в отношении таких названий... А какими правилами вооще регулируется подобные случаи в русском? Вы написали "по правилам", я что-то не припомню... Есть сложившаяся традиция, но ей ведь перед носом у акима не потрясешь. Значит, остается только справочник топонимов. Но его "юрисдикция" на сопредельные территории не распространяется. так что с написанием топонимов, видимо, надо как-то решать по ситуации. Для казахов писать как они хотят, для русских - как надо. Вы вот приучились "Алматы" писать против всех русских традиций, привыкнете и к этому.